# How best to define the "unit of work" that gets parallelised in Apache Beam / Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm new to Apache Beam and Dataflow, and am hoping to use it to automate and speed up the download and processing of a large quantity of remotely-sensed daily or weekly satellite imagery data. For a single output image, the workflow consists of downloading multiple tiles of raw data, mosaicing/stitching them together into a global or regional image, applying some other calculations to those mosaics to extract the actual dataset required from them, and outputting final results to a GCS bucket.

I've got all the individual parts worked out as PTransforms / DoFns for some test runs using Dataflow Notebooks but I'm struggling to work out the best way to split up the work for scaling it up.

Briefly the processing chain is as follows. For each required output image (a unique combination of: date / geographical subset of tiles / raw data product / set of calculations to apply to the raw data), download all tiles to a bucket, copy them to local worker, perform mosaic/other calculations, copy back to bucket. Pseudocode:

```
for date in required_dates:
    for product in required_satellite_products:
        for tile in tiles_in_region:
            # up to 317 tiles ; downloading is slow 
            # can / should we parallelise this part as well as the outermost loop?
            download_tile_to_bucket()
        for required_layer in layers_in_this_product():
            # up to 5 layers
            copy_tiles_to_worker()
            mosaic_tiles()
            extract_layer_and_calculate_output()
            copy_output_to_bucket()
        delete_cached_tiles_from_bucket()
```

So my basic work package / unit of processing would seem to be the output image: just a PCollection of tuples of the (day/area/data product) that defines an output.

The main complication is that each one will need up to 300+ raw data files downloading. The speed of this is probably limited by the bandwidth of the data provider so I think it's worth splitting these download tasks over more workers than the work to process the downloaded tiles.

In developing this I ran the downloads as a separate pipeline and only kicked off the processing once the downloads were all complete. But this isn't ideal as really I want to run everything end to end: I just want to be able to split the download step across more workers than the processing steps because the downloads are so much slower than the other processing steps; plus the downloads total many TB and it gets expensive to cache them for all dates in a bucket before processing and removing any of them.

Is this kind of thing possible or am I thinking about it all wrong?

Comment: Is there any grouping of these images? Or is each image treated as a discrete key - with no aggregation across images?

Comment: Interesting question - at the moment I am considering each image as a discrete output / key. I will in fact subsequently want to aggregate those (e.g. mean of a set of images) although will also want to keep the day-by-day images too.

Comment: this is an interesting use case that may warrant more discussion. Do you have code that does all of the individual operations and you're looking to stitch it up in Beam? Do you download from an API endpoint onto a cloud bucket? Don't you need to download the images from the bucket into the machine running the process? Given that the unit of processing is the output image, you would download all tiles for that output onto a single machine and perform the algorithm right? Can you then try to roughly group neighboring output images with shared tiles together?

Comment: Yes, after download the tiles get copied from the bucket to the worker machine - all tiles for that output. Advantage of putting them onto bucket first is that multiple outputs (up to 5) may be made from the same tiles, which could occur on different machines. That's the closest thing there is to "neighboring" outputs.

Comment: But as the download could be parallelised more than the output creation (up to 317 download tasks for every 5 output tasks), I hoped to spread the downloading over more workers, so one job (make an image) gets branched into many (download all tiles) then recombined (gather all tiles and proceed). I'm just unsure how to structure that kind of dependency.

Comment: Have you looked at Dataflow [Shuffle](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shuffle) mechanism?

Comment: were you able to figyure this out @harrygibson? happy to look at this with you further if you still havent